# VueJS animation transition pages

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, gsap

I'm currently learning VueJS to build single page application (SPA). 
I succeeded to create a Vue Router with 3 test pages (Home, Projects, About).

But now, what I want to do is to animate the components during the transitions of the pages using the JS librairie Greensock.

This is a concept I want to do : http://1700laposte.com/jean-pierre-morin/

I would like a different animation by component when clicking on the nav item and I don't really know where I can write the right code.

The VueJS documentation says that there are differents transitions classes (v-enter, v-leave...) and we can apply somes differents methods to animate.

I tried but I failed :/

I need some explanations please.

Thank you

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail? Have you read the documentation at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html ?

Comment: I tried to make javascript animations when clicking on nav items but I don't know where put the events and the animation code.

Yes I read the documentation but the different examples doesn't answer my problem. In the doc, it's always examples on the same page. I need animation between the pages.

For example, if I am on my home page at ' / ' and I click the projects nav item to go to ' /projects ', I want the content of home page disappears with special js animation and the content of projects page appears with another special js animation.

Comment: There are no "pages" in a Vue app -- routes are just another way to swap between components.  So it's done exactly the same as in the examples in the documentation, just put the transition on the `<router-view>`.

Comment: Thank you it's works on the <router-view> ! But now how can I create differents animations by components?

Comment: I've tried javascript page transitions with vue but also did not get it to work. Nuxt however does provide an easy JS api to use page transitions, have you looked into that?